# Polymer Material Design paper-shadow on touch

Tags: shadow, polymer, material-design

I am working on a website using the [Material Design](https://www.google.com/design/) from Google and the [Polymer-Project](http://www.polymer-project.org/).

According to Google's [Surface Response animation guide](http://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/responsive-interaction.html#responsive-interaction-surface-response) one should eg when tapping an object elevate it for a certain time, along with the ripple effect. Reading the [Paper-shadow docs](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/paper-elements.html#paper-shadow) I found the `animated` parameter can be set to true to animate changes in the z value (depth) of the element.

However, how do I change it back to the initial value? I can set a timer and reapply the initial value, but that doesn't seem like an efficient way to solve this issue. Since it is advised behavior to add this functionality, I think it should be implemented somehow (or maybe it's on its way?)

Does anyone know how to solve this? Here's the current code:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-shadow/paper-shadow.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-ripple/paper-ripple.html">

<polymer-element name="photo-album">

    <template>
        <style>
            :host{
                display: block;
                position: relative;
                background-color: white;
                padding: 20px;
                width: 200px;
            }
            polyfill-next-selector{ content: '.album-header img';}
            .album-header ::content img{
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }
            polyfill-next-selector{ content: '.album-header h2';}
            .album-header ::content h2{
                color: #99182c;
                font-family: 'RobotoDraft', sans-serif;
                font-weight: normal;
                margin: 0;
            }
            polyfill-next-selector{ content: '.album-header h3';}
            .album-header ::content h3{
                color: grey;
                font-size: x-small;
                font-family: 'RobotoDraft', sans-serif;
                font-weight: normal;
                margin: 0;
            }
        </style>

        <paper-shadow z="{{shadowValue}}" animated="true"></paper-shadow>
        <div class="album-header" vertical layout on-tap="{{albumTapped}}">
            <paper-ripple class="recenteringTouch" fit></paper-ripple>
            <content select="img"></content>
            <content select="h2"></content>
            <content select="h3"></content>
        </div>

    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer('photo-album', {
            publish:{
                shadowValue: 1
            },
            albumTapped: function(event, detail, sender){
                this.shadowValue = 3;
            }
        });
    </script>

</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd advise you not to be worried about using ordinary javascript with Polymer. Doing a setTimeout to lower the card back down after a tap makes total sense to me. Try something like:

```
albumTapped: function(event, detail, sender) {
  if (this.recedeTimeout != null) {
    clearTimeout(this.recedeTimeout);
  }
  this.recedeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    this.shadowValue = 1;
    this.recedeTimeout = null;
  }.bind(this), 100);
  this.shadowValue = 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the best way to animate paper-shadow is something like this:

```
<paper-shadow id="paper_shadow" z="1" on-mouseover="{{raise}}" on-mouseout="{{lower}}" animated="true"></paper-shadow>

raise: function(){
        this.$.paper_shadow.setZ('2');
      },

      lower: function() {
        this.$.paper_shadow.setZ('1');
      }
```

This should do the trick of raising and lowering the paper-shadow